# Drupal Errors in a shared host

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, shared-hosting

I have a website made with Drupal hosted in a shared plan. It has more than 50 modules installed. The site works fine for viewers. But there are a few questions.

1. User 1 can't login. But other roles can (like editor, etc. editor has the ability only to add pages and articles.). To check what's happening, I tried to add more permission to an existing user (who can login currently) and uploaded that database to the online server. Then that user couldn't log in.
2. The site crashes when i try to carryout something other than adding articles/pages/blocks in the backend. Adding new modules definitely crashes the db. Things get normal after restoring the database.

What is the reason for this? Is this because of the shared host?

Comment: No... I believe the host is not the problem. But, it is the setting. I'm not familiar with drupal, but you may check the setting again and find the solution on forum like this. :) Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to increase php's memory limit.

In your `settings.php` file. Normally it's located under `sites/default/settings.php` add a new line.

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "256M");
```

For further reading, check this article http://drupal.org/node/76156

Hope this helps...

Comment: I'm in a shared host. So the maximum limit they allow is 64M.

Comment: you can probably set this higher with a php.ini file